# Adding a schema code to one specific page using functions.php file

Tags: functions, child-theme, json, code

I would like to add a schema code I have generated to one specific page on my website using functions.php file on my child theme. How do I do this?

Comment: What is the schema code - a script to include, or some meta tags to go in the header, or something else? That will determine which hook you need to use. Or you can always create a page-specific template using the slug name or the post ID.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest way is to put your code in a function and call it on that specific page.

```
if (! function_exists('my_schema_code')) {
    function my_schema_code(){
       /* schema code... */
    }
}
```

if that page doesnt have a custom file, create one, for example a template or a page. just like Rup said.